# This Account has been suspended. Contact your hosting provider for more information

Tags: dns, cpanel, web-deployment, nameservers

my previous hosting provider is expired then when I click my website it's showing

**This Account has been suspended.
Contact your hosting provider for more information.**

Then I change the hosting provider and I connect my domain with a new hosting provider changing the nameserver. but still website showing
**This Account has been suspended.
Contact your hosting provider for more information.**

Then I talk with the new hosting provider they are telling domain and hosting connect perfectly but I'm still getting the same problem

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is not something anyone can help you with.  Why was your account suspended?  You need to ask before you can fix the problem.  Anyway... quite off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be some kind of cache issue into your system, try to check it on incognito window

Comment: I tried both ways but still getting  the same

Comment: ok then check your website URL on https://whois.net/ this site, and also check your domain DNS setting, the nameserver is updated properly or not with the updated server